# Calling COM method in DLL using the JNI

Tags: dll, com, java-native-interface

I'm trying to integrate with a third party DLL using the JNI. I've written a test class to see if I can call a method in the DLL but I'm getting an "UnsatisfiedLinkError" error.

The class looks like the following:

```
public class MyTest {

    native String ConfigureRequest(String a, String b, String c, String d);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("my_dll");
      }

    @Test
    public void quickTest(){

        String result = this.ConfigureRequest("1", "1", "1", "NoControlBar");

        System.out.println("Result: " + result );

    }

}
```

I have used The [TypeLibrary Viewer](http://www.itripoli.com/itlv.asp) to investigate the DLL and I can see that the method is there (although it says its in the package "EIAComInterface.TxnRequests" so I'm wondering do I need to specify the package somewhere on the method). I can also verify that the method parameters are correct.

Can anyone advise on this please?

Thanks a lot, 
  Gearoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though Jacozoom could be a possible solution to the above problem. In my case, it turns out that I can use SOAP to query the webservice.